# Error with ApiContextfunctoin in netshel paypal

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

How can I solve this error:

```
BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 107: Method [ApiContext]
does not exist.
```

This is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class paypalel extends Controller {
    private $_apiContext;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
            config('services.paypal.client_id'),
            config('services.paypal.secret')
        );

        $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));

    }

    public function getCheckout() {
        $payer = PayPal::Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
        $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,
        // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
        // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

        $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');

        $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('paypalel@getDone'));
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('paypalel@getCancel'));

        $payment = PayPal::Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
        $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

        return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl ); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake at this line

```
 $this->_apiContext = Paypalel::ApiContext(
```

I suppose it should be

```
$this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
```

I hope this will resolve your issue

Add the following lines before your class declaration

```
  use PayPal;
  use Redirect;
```

Comment: Please add the paypal library document url or the git url for paypal

Comment: use PayPal;
  use Redirect;

Comment: use PayPal;
  use Redirect;
you mean it ?

Comment: yes and i hope you have set configuration for facades in config.php in providers array as per the link which you have send